# Why are 'number only' urls so popular/ expensive on Godaddy Auctions? What are they even useful for?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

The idea for domain 'names' is to provide a more memorable/ identifiable alternative to IP address.

However, I noticed that several domains like ####.com have high estimated values on Godaddy Auctions.

These listed are seemingly random numbers.  What are they being used for? Are they memorable to some demographic of people?

or somehow subversive or undercover?

[image]

I navigated to a couple but since they are expired domains I just get godaddy's redirected sales page.   The wayback machine gives Chinese language sites.

Comment: These are four digit numbers and they are probably valuable as a domain name just because of that.

Comment: @StephanLuis In some countries like China, they've been using numbers as URLs since the early 2000's because they were easy to type into non-smart cell phones, which were widely used because landline connections for computers weren't as available as they were in other countries. They likely continued being popular as a result. Domains that are 4 characters and below are considered valuable because they're easier to remember and require less typing. It's pretty rare to find a 4 character or less domain even if it's combination of numbers and letters that isn't snapped up, hence the valuation.

Comment: @dan Sensible reasons... want to write that as an answer?

Comment: I stopped answering questions since becoming a moderator to let other users build up their rep and to avoid unfair competition with them. Once in a  while I'll comment if I don't think an answer is going to result. Feel free to use my comment for an answer, or the basis of one, and mark it as accepted so you earn some more rep (I'll upvote and remove this comment then).